# Group by causing a huge increase in query execution time

Tags: sql, oracle

**EDIT2: Rephrased the whole question so it is more clear**

I have quite long with clause, which generates a sub-query table of 400 rows and 10 columns in under a second from quite a big tables.

However I want to make a group by on that sub-query and thats where the problem arises - when I do that group by and use it further in the with clause the query run for 15 minutes and still no result, so I terminated it.

If I only use the group by and stop the script there, then it runs under a second, with this script:

```
select ROK,d.typ,LIM_DGR_KOEF, LIM_HODNOTA, LIMIT_OD, LIMIT_DO,lek_uvazky,
sum(d.dok_sk_vyp)  suma_fakt,
sum(d.dok_sk_vyp-d.dok_sk_uzn) neuzn_vyk,
sum(d.dok_sk_uzn)  suma_uzn,
sum(d.dok_sk_uct)  suma_uct,
count(*)  as pocet_vyk
from portfolio d
group by ROK,d.typ,LIM_DGR_KOEF, LIM_HODNOTA, LIMIT_OD, LIMIT_DO,lek_uvazky
```

Where `portfolio` is the previous part of the with clause

However, if I use it again as a subquery, e.g.:

```
pf as(
select ROK,d.typ,LIM_DGR_KOEF, LIM_HODNOTA, LIMIT_OD, LIMIT_DO,lek_uvazky,
sum(d.dok_sk_vyp) suma_fakt,
sum(d.dok_sk_vyp-d.dok_sk_uzn) neuzn_vyk,
sum(d.dok_sk_uzn) suma_uzn,
sum(d.dok_sk_uct) suma_uct,
count(*) as pocet_vyk
from portfolio d
group by ROK,d.typ,LIM_DGR_KOEF, LIM_HODNOTA, LIMIT_OD, LIMIT_DO,lek_uvazky
)select * from pf
```

Then the explain plan changes and is very heavier.

Here are the explain plans:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDNLi.jpg

**Is there any way to dictate the optimizer to choose same path as in the faster example?**

Comment: At a minimum, you'd need to post the query plan for both.  It is very hard to speculate about what the optimizer might have done and then to speculate on speculation about why it might have done the thing we're speculating about.

Comment: Please add the execution plan for the original query.

Comment: @JustinCave I have added the plans to imgur album

Comment: Are you aware that portfolio  is a view and not a table?

Comment: It is not defined as a view (maybe the optimiser makes it one for the purposes of the query?) it is the previous part of my with clause. Should I add the whole clause? I dont think that is necessary as that part is same in both queries.

Comment: I'm not talking about **pf** but on **portfolio**. If you'll take a look on the execution plan, you'll see there multiple tables, being joined using nested loops, through their indexes. I'm willing to bet that in the execution plan for the second query (please add it) we will see many hash joins instead.

Comment: The EP make no sense. Did you take both at the same time? Please verify if you get now the same EP..

Comment: Yep I took both at the same time. Is there something like too deep nesting for a with clause (that is the only thing that comes to mind I know I have faced similar problem once)? This is a problem I faced at work, the Oracle version is not the latest, I think it is either 9 or 10 if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the table structures and the execution plan , I can offer two things:

1) Add the proper indexes if they don't exists yet.

2) Create a temporary table with that `WITH` clause, and then use the same select on the table.

Comment: added additional info to the question

Comment: 2 HUGE 'No's. This is Oracle no MySql and Indexes are what killing his query performance in the first place

Comment: Hence the word "proper". The correct indexes can only speed up the query, not hurt it. @dudumarkovitz

Comment: What would you suggest as a  "proper" index for a query with no filtering, based on one medium table with the volume of 10M and multiple other very small tables?

Comment: If he'd show the `with` clause query, then I could have answered. I assume there are joins, filters and ETC. @dudumarkovitz