# GROUP BY causing a performance issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have same issue as [group-by-causing-a-huge-increase-in-query-execution-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468961/group-by-causing-a-huge-increase-in-query-execution-time). I pushed the intermediate result to a table variable (makes no difference if I use a temp table) and declared an appropriate Clustered Index as relevant to my group by clause, i.e.

```
INDEX IX1 CLUSTERED (ContractID, Odometer DESC, FuelTranDate DESC)
```

Querying the results takes about 8 sec. However, as soon as I use the results in a GROUP BY clause (see example below) the query takes forever. The purpose of the query is to check fuel data entry discrepancies.

```
SELECT * FROM @Fuel --8 secs to run.
```

Add GROUP BY clause:

```
;WITH CTEFuelDate_YearMonthPreviousRow AS (
    SELECT *, Year(FuelTranDate) AS FuelTranYr, Month(FuelTranDate) AS FuelTranMn,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ContractID ORDER BY Odometer DESC, FuelTranDate DESC) AS RowNumberPerContract
    FROM @Fuel
), CTE0 AS (
    SELECT curr.*, 
        prev.FuelTranDate AS prevFuelTranDate, 
        prev.Odometer AS prevOdometer,
        prev.Quantity AS prevQuantity,
        curr.Odometer - prev.Odometer AS OdometerDifferential
    FROM CTEFuelDate_YearMonthPreviousRow curr
    JOIN CTEFuelDate_YearMonthPreviousRow prev ON curr.ContractID = prev.ContractID AND curr.RowNumberPerContract + 1 = prev.RowNumberPerContract
)
    SELECT ContractID, Avg(OdometerDifferential) As AvgOdometerDifferential, StDevP(OdometerDifferential) AS StDevPOdometerDifferential
    FROM CTE0
    GROUP BY ContractID
```

Do you need an execution plan as a screen shot or xml?

Comment: Have you tried a [LAG](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/lag.php) function? Instead of the CTE and joining the table with itself?

Comment: where is your @fuel schema and contents?

Comment: My goodness you are my hero - add it as an answer and I can mark it as done. My query gets even longer I only showed half of it and I used LAG further down but not here. I was probably thinking at the time calling LAG three times would be slower than the way I did it - guess not!